# Don't catch exceptions, even from within a try block

Tags: python, exception

Suppose a well-structured OOP Python application, where every call to a method is wrapped in a try block. Now suppose that I'm debugging this application and I want the exceptions to actually be thrown! It would be neigh impossible to replace every `try:` line with `if True:` and to comment out `"""` the `except:` portions, just to debug. Is there any way to tell the Python interpreter that an exceptions thrown by a specific portion of code should stop program execution and print the exception information to stdout?

Python 2.7.3 or 3.2.3 on Kubuntu Linux.

Comment: Seems like a can of worms to me. Suppose that method uses some built-in function like `len`, and that built-in function happens to use exceptions during the normal course of operations. (For example, `len(x)` might iterate through increasing values of i until `x[i]` causes an `IndexError`, then return i.) Then your hypothetical "no catching zone" would tell you `len` is broken, when it's really not.

Comment: @Kevin -- Or even more specifically, in the case of iteration, `__next__` raises a `StopIteration` which gets caught implicitly by the looping construct so it knows to stop calling `__next__`!

Comment: @Kevin,mgilson: I mean that the code would behave just as if it were not wrapped in a try block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Suppose a well-structured OOP Python application, where every call to a method is wrapped in a try block ... "

this doesn't sound well-structured to me at all.  One of the basic principles of exception handling is **ONLY HANDLE EXCEPTIONS THAT YOU KNOW HOW TO DEAL WITH**.  This is the driving principle behind the common "don't use a bare except" statement that you'll see:

```
try:
   do_something()
except:   #BAD BAD BAD
   react_to_exception()
```

"Thrown by a specific portion of code" ... How specific a section of code are we talking about?  If it's a single block, you can always re-raise:

```
try:
    do_something()
except ValueError as e:
    raise e  # or `raise` or `raise SomeOtherError() from e` in more modern pythons.
```

Comment: Thank you. `raise e ` does in fact throw the exception to the environment as I need, but it does not show me which line of code the exception occurred on, only the line of code in which the `raise` statement is found. How might I find which line is culprit? Thanks!

Comment: @dotancohen Why are you catching an exception you don't know how to deal with anyway? Your entire problem arises from you prematurely catching exceptions! Just remove all the `try ... except`s and catch only exceptions you know 1. where they occur, and 2. how to handle them.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This sound like a job for a debugger. I'm only familiar with the debugger for [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), with which you can set an exception breakpoint for any exception.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you want stack trace for debugging purpose. In such case,you can use traceback module where ever you want:

```
import traceback

try:
    func()
except Exception,e:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Or use debugger - pdb

Comment: `sys.excepthook = my_excepthook`: Setup a custom excepthook is also useful. I  am using that for showing a Bug-report window in my program.

Comment: `sys.excepthook` is only called for uncaught exceptions. According to the OP, all exceptions are being caught.