# How to handle exceptions which I do not know the exact names beforehand?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I have a lot of images to handle, and it is possible that some of the images have some problems to open. So I want to handle possible exceptions in my python script. The problem is I do not know what kind of exceptions might be raised during the process of opening an image. This is my script for exception handling:

```
from PIL import Image

# all_im_path is a list containing all the image path
for path in all_im_path:

    try:
        im = Image.open(path)
        ratio = float(im.width) / float(im.height)
        ratios.append(ratio)
        im.close()
    except:
        continue
```

I know from [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025151/6064933) that catching a bare exception is a bad practice. But I do not know beforehand which exception to raise. So my question is how to improve this code. Any suggestions?

Comment: At the very least catch `Exception`, so that memory errors and keyboard interrupts and such are not caught: `except Exception:`

Comment: I'd also move everything but the `Image.open()` call *out* of the `try..except`. Images, once loaded, have a width and height so the `float` calls and division are not going to throw exceptions, nor is appending to a list or closing the open image object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are right, I should only put the image opening statement inside the try .. except block. Other statements do not raise exceptions.